# how to copy data from multiple txt to a single txt file according to the order

Tags: linux, shell-script

I have used the code cat *.txt >> output.txt . This code is doing is its work but here unix is deciding the order in which the files are being copied to my output file which is undesirable as i want the files to be copied according to their occurence or time of generation .
I have also used the below command so i can control the copy format

```
for tablename in 'cat ${current_path}/table.txt(have defined the order)

do 

for data in 'cat path/$tablename.txt

do 
echo "$data" >> final/output.txt

done

done
```

here it is doing its work but generating multiple copies of the single txt as for loop is working .

Answer (score 2):

Assuming I understand the question then

```
   xargs < "${current_path}/table.txt" cat > final/output.txt
```

is all you need. `xargs` will read the "table.txt" file and run `cat` with the files in the specified order, so will output them to stdout, and you redirect stdout to the desired place. Note that this works even if there are so many files that `xargs` executes `cat` more than once, as the redirection is done only once before any `cat` (or even the `xargs`) is executed.

If you want it sorted according to time, then

```
   ls -t | xargs cat > final/output
```

will work if there are no awkward filenames (e.g. embedded spaces or newlines).

Comment: Hi icarus the below command does work.             Ls - t | xargs cat > final/output but there is one problem that is it is copying  the last generated txt file on the top but i want the file which is generated first should be copies to the output file first then the following ones.     For example if there are abc.txt (first files) abd.txt then the output file should have data firat of abc..txt and the the following files. Can this be done

Comment: Does `ls -rt | grep -v output |xargs cat > final/output` do what you want? Can you edit your question to put in some more example data

Comment: I mean i want to append the data in the output file according to the generatiin of the file by using above code the. The output file generated show the data of the last file and then the first it is reversing the order of appending data that is last showing first and first files data showing at the end

Comment: Does the `r` in the `ls -rt` not do what you want? It appears that both I and @joolin are having difficulty in understanding what you are asking for. Please edit your question to show some example data. For example create 3 files `cat`, `dog` and `zebra` each of which just has a line saying `this is cat`, `this is dog` and `this is zebra`. Run `touch dog` so dog is the newest file so the ages of the files do not match the alphabetical order. show us the output of `ls -l` and also your desired output.

Answer (score 2):

```
for tablename in $(cat ${current_path}/table.txt);do
  for word in $(cat path/${tablename}.txt);do
    echo ${word}
  done
done > final/output.txt
```

This should work. I'm not sure what you mean by

> here it is doing its work but generating multiple copies of the single txt as for loop is working

Can you be more specific ?

---

-- Edited -- following the suggestion below.

Comment: This is a correct answer, but it can be improved. One of the things that you can do in the shell is redirect control structures. In this case you can redirect the for loop to the file. Doing so is fractionally more efficient (the shell doesn't need to do the redirection for each `cat`) but also removes the need to "start with a clean file". So the code is just `for tablename in $(cat ${current_path}/table.txt); do cat "$tablename" ; done > final/output.txt`

Comment: True, it avoids _opening_ the `output.txt` file on each iteration.

Comment: Hi have tried this as in my code using the table.txt i am creating seperate $tablename.txt as i have code above also which created diffrent txt. So if you will cat $tablename.txt it will throw error as each $tablename.txt has date row by row and not in a single row ex asdfff                                               
                            gsss.                                               
                            Gsss                                          
  so here cat wont do.

Comment: Hi, I edited the answer following your comment. Basically you need the words in each file to be displayed as lines. I'm not sure about the order